# How to set up a scheduler in JBoss AS 5?

Tags: jboss, schedule

I have scheduled task in JBoss:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <server>
  <mbean code="org.jboss.varia.scheduler.Scheduler" name="acme:service=Scheduler">
   <attribute name="…">…</attribute>
…
  </mbean>
 </server>
```

How to write this task, that  will execute at 1:00 AM on the first day of every month?
Thank You!

Comment: Please name your questions using relevant title.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [EJB Scheduler](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/tutorial/1.0.7/html/Quartz_scheduler_integration.html)?

Otherwise, check [here](http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=320):

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.varia.scheduler.Scheduler" name="jboss.test:service=MyScheduler">
    <attribute name="StartAtStartup">true</attribute>
    <attribute name="SchedulableClass">test.MySchedulable</attribute>
    <attribute name="SchedulableArguments">MySchedulable,100</attribute>
    <attribute name="SchedulableArgumentTypes">java.lang.String,long</attribute>
    <attribute name="InitialStartDate">NOW</attribute>
    <attribute name="SchedulePeriod">5000</attribute>
    <attribute name="InitialRepetitions">10</attribute>
</mbean>
```

Schedulable:

```
package test;
import java.util.Date;
import org.jboss.varia.scheduler.Schedulable;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
public class MySchedulable implements Schedulable
{
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MySchedulable.class);

    private String name;
    private long value;

    public MySchedulable(String name, long value)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        log.info("nt name: " + name + ", value: " + value);
    }

    public void perform(Date now, long repetitions)
    {
        log.info("perform(), time: " + now +", repetitions: " + repetitions +", name: " + name + ", value: " + value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks You!
But how to write this task that will execute at 1:00 AM on the first day of every month? If it possible.. In “SchedulePeriod”  we can specify only time between runs…

Answer (score 0):

How about this

In jboss-service.xml

```
<!-- Put a real date here -->
<attribute name="InitialStartDate">01-01-01 01:00</attribute>
<attribute name="SchedulePeriod">86400000</attribute>
```

Then in Java

```
package com.example.scheduler.job;

import java.util.Date;
import org.jboss.varia.scheduler.Schedulable;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class MyJobScheduler implements Schedulable {

    public MyJobScheduler() {}

    public void perform(Date now, long repetitions) {

         Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
         calendar.setTime(now);
         int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);            
         if(day == 1) {
            // Do stuff
         }
    }
}
```

I know this question is old, but what do you think?